# Check session on hosting server

Tags: php

need to check the `session` on my hosting server. how can i check the `session` in building on not as i am getting the following error

`Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent`

I am putting the Session as

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
```

Any help ?

Comment: this is because your script already sent output before session_start(). can you paste your whole code

Comment: Try to put `ob_start()` before `session_start()`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Session is already running.
If you call the function again, the warning is returned.
You can avoid displaying the warning for the line of code by @:

```
@session_start();
```

Not very nice, but working for me.

Alternatevly, you can use:

```
if(!session_id()) session_start();
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php

Comment: how can i check the session on my hosting server, weather its building or not ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527507/js-function-display-0-results its the same question, its showing 00 results on my hosting server. everything is working cool at localhost and on other server.